# Install Prerequisites on End User Computers to Run Office Solutions using Wix setup

Tags: c#, wix, vsto, wix3.5

I have developed an addin for Microsoft office and have made a setup for this addin using **WIX**. For install and using this addin as a **Prerequisite "visual studio tools for office 2010 runtime"** must be installed in the end user system.So if the end user doesn't have VS2010 tools for office runtime installed,then am redirecting them to the Microsoft page [VSTO2010runtime download](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=44074) .and if user downloads from here and installs then the setup and application will work fine. But recently i came to know about [Microsoft Office 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies Bootstrapper Package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18249). Seems it will automatically download and install all the Prerequisites .But i really don't know how to work with this **Microsoft Office 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies Bootstrapper Package** on WIX.

Is it good way which i did earlier by redirecting end user to the exact page or using this **Microsoft Office 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies Bootstrapper Package**.

**NOTE:**Am using wix installer

Answer (score 1):

The [Deploying an Office Solution by Using Windows Installer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article describes the required steps for deploying Office add-ins. There is no need to include the PIA's bootstrapper to the add-in package. Instead, you need to include only PIAs you referenced in the project.

Comment: but am using WIX installer,is it help me

Comment: WIX is used to build the Windows Installer. It doesn't matter what tool is used to build the installer. The principles and rules are common.